# Mysql Error Code : 1292 Incorrect datetime value : ''

Tags: mysql, datediff, insert-into

I'm trying to insert a record to a table and I get the following error.

```
Mysql Error Code : 1292 Incorrect datetime value : ''
```

Mysql code snip-let is as follows

```
INSERT INTO tbl_dashboard (avg_response)
SELECT cast(ifnull(floor(avg(5 * (DATEDIFF(substring(im.inq_managerreply,-10), im.inq_managerdate) DIV 7)
       + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400001234000123440',
                        7 * WEEKDAY(im.inq_managerdate) + WEEKDAY(substring(im.inq_managerreply,-10)) + 1, 1))),'not_applicable')AS CHAR(45)) 'average_response_time_in_working_days'
  FROM inq_manager im
```

There are no errors in executing the select statement which gives the average response time excluding the weekends but when I try to insert the above to my table the error is given. 
The data type of the tbl_dashboard is avg_response char(45)

How can I overcome this . Please help

Comment: I'd like to say this is the ugliest query I've ever seen. Unfortunately, it isn't.

Comment: Probably, you need to revise the whole logic of whatever you doing with this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will matter, but it is worth a shot. And i'll delete this if it doesn't help but maybe

```
INSERT INTO tbl_dashboard (avg_response) VALUES
(SELECT cast(ifnull(floor(avg(5 * (DATEDIFF(substring(im.inq_managerreply,-10), im.inq_managerdate) DIV 7)
       + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400001234000123440',
                        7 * WEEKDAY(im.inq_managerdate) + WEEKDAY(substring(im.inq_managerreply,-10)) + 1, 1))),'not_applicable')AS CHAR(45)) 'average_response_time_in_working_days'
  FROM inq_manager im)
```